# How can I use for the generalized logistic equation a series approximation?

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

The question is how can I show the following approximation stated in this paper.

I have tried to follow , but I am not pretty sure if the following results are correct

Generalized logistic growth modeling of the COVID-19 outbreak: comparing the dynamics in the 29 provinces
in China and in the rest of the world

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11071-020-05862-6

Eq 5, 6

They have written an equation similar to

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{Y}\frac{dY}{dt}=\frac{   A  e^{-  b t}}{ 1 -  A  e^{- b  t}}   
\end{align}
following the definition of the serie geometric

\begin{align}
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} Ae^{-n b t} = 1 +   e^{- b  t}+
  e^{-2 b  t} +  e^{- 3b  t} + \ldots
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{Y}\frac{dY}{dt}=
 \frac{   A  e^{-  b t}}{ 1 -  A  e^{- b  t}}  = A e^{-  b t} \left(  1 +   e^{- b  t}+
 e^{-2 b  t} +  e^{- 3b  t} + \ldots\right)   
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{Y}\frac{dY}{dt}=
 \frac{   A  e^{-  b t}}{ 1 -  A  e^{- b  t}}  = A   e^{-  b t} +   e^{- 2b  t}+
 e^{-3 b  t} +  e^{- 4 b  t} + \ldots   
\end{align}
for long term, it can be written after substitution the approximation.

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{Y}\frac{dY}{dt}= \frac{   A  e^{-  b t}}{ 1 -  A  e^{- b  t}}  = A   e^{-  b t}   
\end{align}

Any suggestion

Comment: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=\frac{Ae^{-\lambda t}}{1-Ae^{-\lambda t}}\mathrm{d}t$$
Let $u=1-Ae^{-\lambda t}$ which gives $\mathrm{d}u=\lambda Ae^{-\lambda t}\mathrm{d}t$ hence
$$\int\frac{1}{y}\mathrm{d}y=\lambda\int\frac{1}{u}\mathrm{d}u$$
Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

> the leading behavior of the growth rate at long times

$$\gamma  \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\epsilon_0  e^{-\gamma  t}\right)^k=\frac{\gamma  \epsilon_0  e^{-\gamma t}}{1-\epsilon_0  e^{-\gamma t}}$$
In the sum on the left all ther terms with exponent $k$ larger that  $1$ can be neglected for large $t$.

And it can be approximated by $\epsilon_0  e^{-\gamma  t}$.

Just to see what happens, suppose $\epsilon_0 =\gamma=1$ and $t=5$, and let's see the values when exponent $k$ increases

$$
\begin{array}{r|r}
 k & e^{-5k}\\
\hline
 1 & 0.006738 \\
 2 & 0.000045 \\
 3 & 3.06\cdot 10^{-7} \\
 4 & 2.06\cdot 10^{-9}  \\
 5 & 1.39\cdot 10^{-11}  \\
\end{array}
$$